# Flatten or Shrink Image in Button Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-button

I am Using Android Studio I have an .png Image in my drawable folder in all formats(hdi,ldpi etc),
The Problems is i have set the button background as drawable image when i run application image seems to flatten or shrunk I have no idea why it happens and never faced a problem in my older ADT bundle.

**Here is my Layout File**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/splash_screen_appname"
    android:typeface="serif"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/splash_screen_version"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/splash_screen_quotes"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/splash_screen_quotes"
        android:layout_below="@+id/splash_screen_appname"
        android:text="Version 9.0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/splash_screen_quotes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:text="“when you don&apos;t create things, you become defined by your tastes rather than ability. your tastes only narrow &amp; exclude people. so create.” "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/splash_screen_companyname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="By - Intralane"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/splash_screen_continue"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_action_next"
        android:layout_above="@+id/splash_screen_companyname"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="58dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**And Here is The Image or Screen Snap**

[image: Flatten Image]

**And Here is the original .png File(image) from drawable folder**

[image: Original Image From Drawable Folder]

PS : The Issue Usually Appears in Platform 3.0+ , in AVD 2.3 Its Fine , Image is Circle, I have made previous project where i have used circle .png image like above and none of them have problem likes these even in Platforms 3.0+ using ADT Bundle

Comment: try using the image with higher resolutoin, or what you can do is use imageView instead of image button and give the scale type of button as "fitXY".

Comment: why dont you use ImageView instead of Button?

Comment: It has same Problem with all views

Comment: @krunalpatel It is higer Resolution , it works fine once and sometimes (most) this error occurs

Comment: try using imageView and add the scale type for imageview to "fitxy"

Comment: ImageView without scale type Works! , But why with Buttons? I have use Buttons in previous projects that has published 10days ago and no issues wile using ADT. Any Bug?